# Spring - cannot load application.yml in @Component serializer in unit test (In the test class @Value is loaded correctly)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

I want to load the timezone configured in `application.yml` in my Spring Boot application(1.5.6). Spring is 5.0.4.

I see it loaded in my test class:

```
@Slf4j
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest // to load test application.yml
public class KafkaUserPurchaseDTOTest {
    private static String jsonDataUpdate = "";

    @Value("${time-zone.name}")
    private String timezone;  // <---------- the value is loaded here

    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void prepare() throws IOException {
        InputStream in = KafkaUserPurchaseDTOTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/fixture/kafka-data-user-purchase-update.json");
        jsonDataUpdate = IOUtils.toString(in, Charset.defaultCharset());
    }

    @Test
    public void testConvertJsonToPurchaseDTO() throws IOException {
        // given
        assert !jsonDataUpdate.isEmpty() : "Must load the json file";
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false); // just take the fields we need
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);
        mapper.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Budapest"));
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE, true);

        // when
        UserPurchaseDTO dto = mapper.readValue(jsonDataUpdate, UserPurchaseDTO.class);  // <------------ here we enter serializer....
        // then
        Assert.assertNotNull(dto);
        Assert.assertNotNull(dto.getMemberId());
        Assert.assertNotNull(dto.getLastBuyDate());
        // See the example JSON for exact values
        Assert.assertEquals("2018-03-19 09:16:11", DateTimeUtil.formatDateWithMilliPart(dto.getLastBuyDate(), false));
        Assert.assertEquals(790849L, dto.getMemberId().longValue());
    }

    //@Test TODO more test on empty/null values

}
```

But in the serializer, the same value is not loaded, even when it is annotated with `@Component`.

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class KafkaUserPurchaseDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<UserPurchaseDTO> {

    @Value("${time-zone.name}")
    private String timezone;

    public KafkaUserPurchaseDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public KafkaUserPurchaseDeserializer(Class<?> c) {
        super(c);
    }



    @Override
    public UserPurchaseDTO deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        JsonNode root = parser.getCodec().readTree(parser);
        UserPurchaseDTO dto = new UserPurchaseDTO();
        String Id = root.get(UserPurchaseDTO.JSON_PROP_KAFKA_FK_MEMBER_PK).asText();
        if (StringUtils.hasText(Id)) {
            try {
                dto.setMemberId(Long.parseLong(Id));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                log.error("Cannot format {} to number", Id, e);
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            log.error("Cannot find  user id for this message: {}", root.toString());
            return null;
        }
        String lastBuy = root.get(UserPurchaseDTO.JSON_PROP_KAFKA_LAST_DATE).textValue();
        if (StringUtils.hasText(lastBuy)) {
            try {
                dto.setLastBuyDate(DateTimeUtil.convertDateToAppConfigTimeZone(timezone, lastBuy, false));   // <----------------- here: timezone = null
            } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
                log.error("Cannot parse {} to date", lastBuy, e);
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            log.info("User Purchase comes without last buy date. The node has content: {}", lastBuy);
        }
        return dto;
    }
}
```

Why? They are not in the same context?

Comment: Please add a stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Try definie this bean in your configuration:

```
@Bean
public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer(){
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        }
```

Reference: [1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/821#issuecomment-42614341), [2](https://github.com/berlin-ab/springbootblog/tree/blog/configuration)

Answer (score 0):

Now having asked around, I found that I am creating another `ObjectMapper` instead of using that of the Spring context. I stop instantiating it and just use `@Autowired` and it begins to work.

```
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper mapper;
```

I also deleted the part of configuring this `mapper` because it should be done in `application.yml` if I load it from context.